# Oracle inequality operator: ¬=

Tags: oracle

Oracle SQL [supposedly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions002.htm#i1033286) has four inequality operators:

1. `!=`
2. `^=`
3. `<>`
4. `¬=`

([PL/SQL operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS235) are a little different.  They allow `~=` instead of `¬=`.  But that is not directly relevant here.)

The manual includes the warning "Some forms of the inequality condition may be unavailable on some platforms."  This applies to at least the 4th option, `¬=`.  That syntax doesn't work for me on Windows, Linux, or Solaris.

My questions are:

1. What platforms support `¬=`?
2. What platforms, if any, do *not* support `!=`, `^=`, or `<>`?  Is it worth avoiding one of those to ensure my code is as portable as possible?

Comment: Of course he has seen it, he submitted an answer for it...

Comment: The doc reference you link to does not mention the fourth option. The first 3 all work fine though.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp If you look at "(Note 1)": "the ASCII character with decimal value 170".  And if you open the PDF version of the document (the PDF link at the top-right of the page) you can see the character on page 473.

Comment: thanks, didn't see that initially.

Comment: @jonearles: there *is* no ASCII character with a decimal value of 170. In fact ASCII characters only go up to 127, by definition. So they probably mean some other ASCII-based encoding. One can only guess which one they mean.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - "¬" is the "not" character on IBM mainframes, and although there's an extended ASCII definition it really only exists in EBCDIC.  AFAICT only supported on IBM mainframes - see my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my best guess as to the derivation and availability of the various inequality operators:

- `<>` - the original.  Used by a number of languages (BASIC, Pascal, etc).
       Probably available on all platforms.
- `!=` - from C and it's derivatives (C, C++, Java, C#, etc, blah).  I expect
       this is available on all platforms.
- `¬=` - This operator is probably only available on IBM mainframes.  I know
       it's not supported on HP-UX as I just tried it.  Near and dear
       to my heart.  From the language PL/I (that's capital 'i', not '1', 
       although it represents the Roman numeral "one", and thus the language
       is "pee ell one".  I knew you wanted to know that :-), IBM's bastard
       stepchild...ahem, I mean "delightful combination" of FORTRAN, Algol,
       and a touch of COBOL.  PL/I was the second high-level computer
       language I learned and the first one I used in making a living as
       a software developer.  From the Good Old Days, when men were men,
       women were women, and computers were water-cooled.  Isn't that
       right, Josiah..?  (And ten points extra credit for those who can
       identify where THAT line comes from!)
- `^=` - I suspect this is meant to be similar to the preceding "IBM-only"
       operator, making it an "IBM-ish" operator for use on computers which
       lack the IBM "¬" (not) character.  Probably supported on all platforms.

FWIW I always use `<>`.  Old habits, like old programmers, die hard.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I always use !=. I do not know about the others, but != has always worked for me on windows and linux.