# Oracle <> , != , ^= operators

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle, query-optimization

I want to know the difference of those operators, mainly their performance difference.

I have had a look at [Difference between <> and != in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856439/difference-between-and-in-sql), it has no performance related information.

Then I found this on [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm),
it suggests that in 10.2 onwards the performance can be quite different.

I wonder why? does `!=` always perform better then `<>`?

NOTE: Our tests, and performance on the live system shows, changing from `<>` to `!=` has a big impact on the time the queries return in. I am here to ask WHY this is happening, not whether they are same or not. I know semantically they are, but in reality they are different.

Comment: hmmm... I don't exactly trust a random e-mail posted on a blog. Have _you_ actually got any evidence to suggest a difference?

Comment: exactly, using `<>` or `!=` is the same.

Comment: Test it yourself and see what you find.  And as @Ben noted, a blog post doth not truth make.  I've never encountered this but on the other hand I haven't looked for it.  Let us know what you find.

Comment: @Ben yeh, on our live system change from <> to != , an oracle query which never returns, now finish in seconds. you really need a massive amount of data to show the difference, select on 1 or 2 rows doesn't matter. also http://www.dba-oracle.com is a great source to learn oracle, A: it not a blog. B: it was't a eamil, its a fact given by a experienced oracle book author. Respect is not something a programmer need to have, its the basic attitude any human being should have

Comment: @shanyangqu, I don't see any disrespect and didn't intend any. Although dba-oracle.com may be a good resource it did link to a blog post containing a e-mail without any attempt to authenticate the source of the mail or verify the veracity of the statements therein. I did actually do a little test to see what difference it would make on a 40m row table as I was interested. The statements returned within 0.1s of each other. I believe evidence is required before I will trust a statement and I wasn't able to provide that evidence myself. Have you actually got any evidence to suggest a difference?

Comment: @shanyangqu, isn't it like that you run query containing "!=" and immediately after that you run the same query with "<>"? If yes, the results from previous query are probably cached in Main Memory and this is why the latter performs very fast. Can you describe more precisely your test scenario?

Comment: Dba-oracle.com is a shoddy website that reports anything and everything it finds about Oracle with the sole aim of getting itself to the top of Google results and driving hits. Never click on these links!

Comment: I can say that even querries that take half and hour show absolutely no performance-difference with regards to `<>` vs `!=`. And why would they? The execution plan is identical, even the generated query-tree is identical.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have tested the performance of the different syntax for the not equal operator in Oracle.  I have tried to eliminate all outside influence to the test.

I am using an 11.2.0.3 database.  No other sessions are connected and the database was restarted before commencing the tests.

A schema was created with a single table and a sequence for the primary key

```
CREATE TABLE loadtest.load_test (
  id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  a VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
  n NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  t TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE loadtest.load_test_seq
START WITH 0
MINVALUE 0;
```

The table was indexed to improve the performance of the query.

```
ALTER TABLE loadtest.load_test
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_load_test
PRIMARY KEY (id)
USING INDEX;

CREATE INDEX loadtest.load_test_i1
ON loadtest.load_test (a, n);
```

Ten million rows were added to the table using the sequence, `SYSDATE` for the timestamp and random data via DBMS_RANDOM (A-Z) and (0-99) for the other two fields.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM load_test;

COUNT(*)
----------
10000000

1 row selected.
```

The schema was analysed to provide good statistics.

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS(ownname => 'LOADTEST', estimate_percent => NULL, cascade => TRUE);
```

The three simple queries are:-

```
SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n <> 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;

SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n != 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;

SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n ^= 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;
```

These are exactly the same with the exception of the syntax for the not equals operator (not just <> and != but also ^= )

First each query is run without collecting the result in order to eliminate the effect of caching.

Next timing and autotrace were switched on to gather both the actual run time of the query and the execution plan.

```
SET TIMING ON

SET AUTOTRACE TRACE
```

Now the queries are run in turn.  First up is <>

```
> SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n <> 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;

26 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.12

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2978325580

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY        |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| LOAD_TEST_I1 |  9898K|    47M|  6132   (2)| 00:01:14 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("N"<>5)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      22376  consistent gets
      22353  physical reads
          0  redo size
        751  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        459  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         26  rows processed
```

Next !=

```
> SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n != 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;

26 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.13

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2978325580

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY        |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| LOAD_TEST_I1 |  9898K|    47M|  6132   (2)| 00:01:14 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("N"<>5)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      22376  consistent gets
      22353  physical reads
          0  redo size
        751  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        459  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         26  rows processed
```

Lastly ^=

```
> SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM load_test WHERE n ^= 5 GROUP BY a ORDER BY a;

26 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.10

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2978325580

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY        |              |    26 |   130 |  6626   (9)| 00:01:20 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| LOAD_TEST_I1 |  9898K|    47M|  6132   (2)| 00:01:14 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("N"<>5)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      22376  consistent gets
      22353  physical reads
          0  redo size
        751  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        459  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         26  rows processed
```

The execution plan for the three queries is identical and the timings 2.12, 2.13 and 2.10 seconds.

It should be noted that whichever syntax is used in the query the execution plan always displays <>

The tests were repeated ten times for each operator syntax.  These are the timings:-

```
<>

2.09
2.13
2.12
2.10
2.07
2.09
2.10
2.13
2.13
2.10

!=

2.09
2.10
2.12
2.10
2.15
2.10
2.12
2.10
2.10
2.12

^=

2.09
2.16
2.10
2.09
2.07
2.16
2.12
2.12
2.09
2.07
```

Whilst there is some variance of a few hundredths of the second it is not significant.  The results for each of the three syntax choices are the same.

The syntax choices are parsed, optimised and are returned with the same effort in the same time.  There is therefore no perceivable benefit from using one over another in this test.

"Ah BC", you say, "in my tests I believe there is a real difference and you can not prove it otherwise".

Yes, I say, that is perfectly true.  You have not shown your tests, query, data or results. So I have nothing to say about your results.  I have shown that, with all other things being equal, it doesn't matter which syntax you use.

"So why do I see that one is better in my tests?"

Good question.  There a several possibilities:-

1. Your testing is flawed (you did not eliminate outside factors -
   other workload, caching etc You have given no information about
   which we can make an informed decision)
2. Your query is a special case (show me the query and we can discuss it).
3. Your data is a special case (Perhaps - but how - we don't see that either).
4. There is some other outside influence.

I have shown via a documented and repeatable process that there is no benefit to using one syntax over another.  I believe that <> != and ^= are synonymous.

If you believe otherwise fine, so

a) show a documented example that I can try myself

and

b) use the syntax which you think is best.  If I am correct and there is no difference it won't matter.  If you are correct then cool, you have an improvement for very little work.

"But Burleson said it was better and I trust him more than you, Faroult, Lewis, Kyte and all those other bums."

Did he say it was better?  I don't think so.  He didn't provide any definitive example, test or result but only linked to someone saying that != was better and then quoted some of their post.

Show don't tell.

Comment: Burleson implies that: *"These "not equal" operators are **supposed to be equivalent**, but ..."*

Comment: +1 for the test case.  (But no bounty, since that's meant to be a reward for anyone who can prove the opposite.  Although I think you will, by default, win half the bounty anyway in a few hours.)

Comment: @ypercube.  ...but here is a guy saying otherwise.  Burleson should have tested it and must take some responsibility for that, since he is a well linked source.

Comment: @jonearles.  Fair enough.  I hope someone does win it (but I think that proving it isn't likely).

Comment: @BrokenCrust: You misunderstood me. I totally agree with your answer except for the *Did he (Burleson) say it was better? I don't think so.* He didn't say it but he implied it. Well linked or not, such inaccurate and obviously false assertions in a site that claims to be Top Oracle-DBA stuff, makes them appear scrupulous - at best.

Comment: To be _absolutely_ certain this was a fair test you should have disconnected the disks as well... :-).

Comment: @ypercube.  I think we are agreeing.  Whilst he didn't implicitly say != was better he vaguely implied it and because his site is a trusted source for many that vague implication gets more weight than it deservers.  IMO Burleson's posts are more of a "how to" guide than a "whys this work like this" investigation (like Kyte et al).  He has a different focus and audience and has been caught out with a sloppy bit of re-posting.

Comment: @Ben. I didn't entirely eliminate outside factors (other server load network traffic etc) but the variance from this was equal across the three syntax tests and mitigated by repetition of each query and so I'm confident that disk activity did not favour or hinder one particular syntax.

Answer (score 19):

You reference the article on the Burleson site.  Did you follow the link to the Oracle-L archive?  And did you read the other emails replying to the email Burleson cites?

I don't think you did, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question.  Because there is no fundamental difference between `!=`  and `<>`.  The original observation was almost certainly a fluke brought about by ambient conditions in the database.  Read the responses from [Jonathan Lewis](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Performance-Difference-Between-and,1) and [Stephane Faroult](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Performance-Difference-Between-and,3) to understand more.

---

> " Respect is not something a programmer need to have, its the basic
>   attitude any human being should have"

Up to a point.  When we meet a stranger in the street then of course we should be courteous and treat them with respect.

But if that stranger wants me to design my database application in a specific way to "improve performance" then they should have a convincing explanation and some bulletproof test cases to back it up.  An isolated anecdote from some random individual is not enough.

Comment: FWIW - I'll take Jonathan Lewis's word on anything Oracle-wise.

Comment: @Bob - In a sense, I'm not sure he would want you to. The reason why the Jonathan Lewis's of this world are so useful is because the stuff they say is usually testable and reproducible. You should probably check what they say rather than always "take their word for it" - not least because that is a great way of cementing it in your memory ;-)

Comment: sometimes i wish the internet had a delete button for times like this.

Answer (score 12):

The writer of [the article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm), although a book author and the purveyor of some useful information, does not have a good reputation for accuracy.  In this case the article was merely a mention of [one persons observations](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Performance-Difference-Between-and) on a well known Oracle mailing list.  If you read through the responses you will see the assumptions of the post challenged, but no presumption of accuracy.  Here are some excerpts:

> Try running your query through explain plan (or autotrace) and see
>   what that says...
>   According to this, "!=" is considered to be the same as "<>"...
>   Jonathan Lewis

Jonathan Lewis is a well respected expert in the Oracle community.

> Just out of curiosity... Does the query optimizer generate a different
>   execution plan for the two queries? Regards, Chris

.

> Might it be bind variable peeking in action? The certain effect of
>   writing != instead of <> is to force a re-parse. If at the first
>   execution the values for :id were different and if you have an
>   histogram on claws_doc_id it could be a reason. And if you tell me
>   that claws_doc_id is the primary key, then I'll ask you what is the
>   purpose of counting, in particular when the query in the EXISTS clause
>   is uncorrelated with the outer query and will return the same result
>   whatever :id is. Looks like a polling query. The code surrounding it
>   must be interesting.
>
> Stéphane Faroult

.

> I'm pretty sure the lexical parse converts either != to <> or <> to
>   !=, but I'm not sure whether that affects whether the sql text will
>   match a stored outline.

.

> Do the explain plans look the same? Same costs?

The following response is from the original poster.

> Jonathan,    Thank you for your answer.  We did do an explain plan on
>   both versions of the statement and they were identical, which is what
>   is so puzzling about this.  According to the documentation, the two
>   forms of not equal are the same (along with ^= and one other that I
>   can't type), so it makes no sense to me why there is any difference in
>   performance.
>
> Scott Canaan

.

> Not an all inclusive little test but it appears at least in 10.1.0.2
>   it gets pared into a "<>" for either (notice the filter line for each
>   plan)

.

> Do you have any Stored Outline ? Stored Outlines do *exact* (literal)
>   matches so if you have one Stored Outline for, say, the SQL with a
>   "!=" and none for the SQL with a "<>" (or a vice versa), the Stored
>   Outline might be using hints ? (although, come to think of it, your
>   EXPLAIN PLAN should have shown the hints if executing a Stored Outline
>   ?)

.

> Have you tried going beyond just explain & autotrace and running a
>   full 10046 level 12 trace to see where the slower version is spending
>   its time?  This might shed some light on the subject, plus - be sure
>   to verify that the explain plans are exactly the same in the 10046
>   trace file (not the ones generated with the EXPLAIN= option), and in
>   v$sqlplan.  There are some "features" of autotrace and explain that
>   can cause it to not give you an accurate explain plan.
>
> Regards, Brandon

.

> Is the phenomenon totally reproducible ?
>
> Did you check the filter_predicates and access_predicates of the plan,
>   or just the structure. I don't expect any difference, but a change in
>   predicate order can result in a significant change in CPU usage if you
>   are unlucky.
>
> If there is no difference there, then enable rowsource statistics
>   (alter session set "_rowsource_execution_statistics"=true) and run the
>   queries, then grab the execution plan from V$sql_plan and join to
>   v$sql_plan_statistics to see if any of the figures about last_starts,
>   last_XXX_buffer_gets, last_disk_reads, last_elapsed_time give you a
>   clue about where the time went.
>
> If you are on 10gR2 there is a /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ hint you
>   can use instead of the "alter session".
>
> Regards Jonathan Lewis

At this point the thread dies and we see no further posts from the original poster, which leads me to believe that either the OP discovered an assumption they had made that was not true or did no further investigation.

I will also point out that if you do an explain plan or autotrace, you will see that the comparison is always displayed as `<>`.

Here is some test code.  Increase the number of loop iterations if you like.  You may see one side or the other get a higher number depending on the other activity on the server activity, but in no way will you see one operator come out consistently better than the other.

```
DROP TABLE t1;
DROP TABLE t2;
CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT level c1 FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=144000);
CREATE TABLE t2 AS (SELECT level c1 FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=144000);

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED

DECLARE
   vStart  Date;
   vTotalA Number(10) := 0;
   vTotalB Number(10) := 0;
   vResult Number(10);
BEGIN   
   For vLoop In 1..10 Loop
      vStart := sysdate;
      For vLoop2 In 1..2000 Loop
         SELECT count(*) INTO vResult FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1 = 777 AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.c1 <> 0);
      End Loop;
      vTotalA := vTotalA + ((sysdate - vStart)*24*60*60);

      vStart := sysdate;
      For vLoop2 In 1..2000 Loop
         SELECT count(*) INTO vResult FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1 = 777 AND EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.c1 != 0);
      End Loop;
      vTotalB := vTotalB + ((sysdate - vStart)*24*60*60);

      DBMS_Output.Put_Line('Total <>: ' || RPAD(vTotalA,8) || '!=: ' || vTotalB);
      vTotalA := 0;
      vTotalB := 0;
   End Loop;

END;
```

Comment: where is the "The writer of the article, although a book author and the purveyor of some useful information, does not have a good reputation for accuracy" came from? you have to give some evidence please. without prove I am afraid I have to call you a liar.

Comment: Have you compared explain plans, autotrace results, 10046 level 12 trace output?  Have you filed an SR with Oracle?  Can you produce a test case similar to mine, but with different results showing a benefit to one not equals form over the other?

Comment: You are welcome to not beleive me without proof.  Here are some things that lead me to my conclusion:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:47466211228419
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:35336203098853
http://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2005/04/11/banned-by-burleson/
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/12/28/missing-the-point/
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/01/02/superfluous-updates/
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/analysing-statspack8/
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/scientific-method/

Comment: http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/untested.html
http://kevinclosson.wordpress.com/2007/07/17/oracle-doesnt-scale-without-multiple-log-writer-processes/
http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Recent-Email-from-Don-Burleson,1
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/dmca/
http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/firefox/
http://www.oaktable.net/content/burleson-buys-bmc
http://nlitchfield.blogspot.com/2005_04_01_archive.html

Comment: its a dog fight between Jonathan and Burleson, how sad Jonathan used his wordpress to attack other people. money? customer? jealous, competition? I don't care. but it seems all your conclusions come from Jonathan's mouth, its personal, and you just can't take one man's word against another man

Comment: Huh?  Check the links again.  I cite five other individuals not including the numerous corroborations in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

A Programmer will use `!=`

A DBA  will use `<>`

If there is a different execution plan it may be that there are differences in the query cache or statistics for each notation. But I don't really think it is so.

Edit:

What I mean above. In complex databases there can be some strange side effects. I don't know oracle good enough, but I think there is an Query Compilation Cache like in SQL Server 2008 R2.
If a query is compiled as new query, the database optimiser calculates a new execution plan depending on the current statistics. If the statistics has changed it will result in a other, may be a worse plan.

Comment: May be ;) I have seen a lot of code an if a programmer makes a query it's at the most `!=`

Comment: That's probably cause programmers are used to that from other languages (.net C#, vb, java, c, c++, etc.)

Comment: I'm both an OCP developer and OCP DBA, which should I be using? :-) FWIW, I tend to use `!=` rather than `<>`

Comment: Sometimes I catch myself doing some mixing :)

Comment: Actually the (ANSI)  SQL standard **only** defines `<>`. `!=` is an extension by some (if not all) DBMS.

Comment: Personally I always use `<>` when writing SQL.  I use `!=` when writing C or one of its derivatives.  I use `~=` when writing Smalltalk.  I use `^=` (should actually be a funky IBM-esque "straight-bar-with-vertical-descender' character instead of a caret, but what can you do?) when writing PL/I (which I haven't touched for nearly 25 years).  There's a TON of different ways to say "NOT EQUAL" - which I seem to recall is what you use in COBOL.  :-)

Comment: @aF - hey, me too.  Where's my raise?!?!?

Comment: @BobJarvis != faster then <> has been tested proven, the question is not ask "if the have any difference", the question is why

Comment: I used to be a programmer some 30 years ago.  When I learned SQL,  "<>" was available, but "!=" was not.  So I got into the habit of using "DBA style" in this case.  That doesn't make me a DBA or a programmer.  Come on, kids.

Comment: " != faster then <> has been tested proven". Horse feathers! Where are the benchmarks?

Comment: I can't find any reliable (i.e. defined, repeatable process) examples of one being faster than the other. When I tested this against a table with nearly 65 million records the difference was tiny and not enough to postulate about their relative efficiency. Perhaps if the table had 500 million records... but I'm not that interested.

Comment: Not constructive.  Voting to close.

Comment: @BobJarvis Perhaps you can answer my (somewhat) related question about inequality operators: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9305925/409172

Comment: +1 Not because for the answer's accuracy, but because it could be a nice Database joke you can crack while team building exercises :)