# Select value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Oracle SQL query which I use to make checks for number:

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID = ?
```

I want to select all values different than the value `12`. How I must edit the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to return values that are not set at all?

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID != 12
```

Will only return values that have MSYSTEMGROUPID  set to a value.

If you want Both values not equal to 12 and values that are not set at all, use this:

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID  IS NULL OR MSYSTEMGROUPID != 12
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two [not equals operators](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm) in Oracle.  The `<>` operator, which is the ANSI SQL standard, and the `!=` operator, which is supported by most if not all relational databases.  Conceptually, they should provide the same results, however according to [this post](http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Performance-Difference-Between-and), they might result in different execution plans affecting performance.

Your query can be expressed as:

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID != 12
```

or:

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID <> 12
```

You could also use the [NOT IN operator](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm#i1004774) if you wanted to support multiple values.  If you wanted to exclude 12, 15 and 20, you could do:

```
SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID NOT IN (12, 15, 20)
```

Comment: The "official" (read ANSI SQL) operator would be `<>`, but nearly all (if not all) DBMS also support the non-standard `!=` operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Yea, the link I provided goes into some interesting details on that, pointing out `!=` and `<>` might result in different execution plans.  Who knew.

Comment: Interesting read, but I guess Stéphane's explanation (new execution plan/bind variable peeking) is probably the most likely reason. The `<>` isn't different by default.

Comment: That particular article was discussed (a lot) and pretty much debunked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003127/oracle-operators, cc @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 SELECT * from MANAGEDSYSTEMGROUPS where MSYSTEMGROUPID != 12
```