# Oracle difference between !=(<>) and not in

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Today I heard that a query with `<>` will take more time to execute than one with `not in`.
I tried to test this and with an equal plan had the following time results:

`select * from test_table where test <> 'test'
0,063 seconds
select * from test_table where test not in ('test')
0,073 seconds`

**So the question is, what is the difference between `<>` and `not in` for a single condition and what is better to use.**

Comment: P.S. Row "test" is not indexed

Comment: Be interested in knowing what the source was for that advice you got.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Source was our company dba. But I haven't got any explanations from him.

Comment: Are you sure he wasn't talking about `not exists` vs. `not in` and claiming one was faster than the other?  That's a more common argument.

Comment: Oh God, not [this thread again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12003127/409172).  There are some *popular* sources that claim magical performance benefits by using a different operator.  But they are not *reliable* sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not the column is indexed, I would expect both queries to perform a full scan on the table, i.e the query plan is essentially the same.  The small timing difference you noted is probably insignificant - run the *same* query more than once and you will get different timings.

Having said that I would use `<>` because it is more natural.

Comment: But realy, "not in" expect list, even if it is a list of one element, opposite <> expect one element. Is there realy nothing special between two of this ?maybe in other case of table structure

Comment: If the query plans are the same (and they are if you check) then there is no performance difference between the two methods.

Comment: You might also check the query plans to see if a transformation has been applied to turn them both into the same SQL behind the scenes anyway. It would appear on one of the lines under "Predicate Information (identified by operation id):". If a transformation has been applied then that should be conclusive, and would explain why the cost is the same. Then you can take them both to your DBA and innocently ask him to explain ;)